# Timed out waiting for a node assignment. while creating topic in provided MSK cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I have EC2 as a client to create topics and when i execute the command to create it, it fails, I'm using this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/create-topic.html
but is not working for me.